# Rails routing to the wrong controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, activeadmin

Here is the output of 'rake routes'

```
$ rake routes
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)            devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)            devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)           devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)           devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)       devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)      devise/passwords#edit
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)           devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)             devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                    devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)            devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)               devise/registrations#edit
                         PUT    /users(.:format)                    devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)                    devise/registrations#destroy
              admin_root        /admin(.:format)                    admin/dashboard#index
         admin_dashboard        /admin/dashboard(.:format)          admin/dashboard#index
              admin_user PUT    /admin/users/:id(.:format)          admin/users#update
batch_action_admin_users POST   /admin/users/batch_action(.:format) admin/users#batch_action
             admin_users GET    /admin/users(.:format)              admin/users#index
                         POST   /admin/users(.:format)              admin/users#create
          new_admin_user GET    /admin/users/new(.:format)          admin/users#new
         edit_admin_user GET    /admin/users/:id/edit(.:format)     admin/users#edit
                         GET    /admin/users/:id(.:format)          admin/users#show
                         PUT    /admin/users/:id(.:format)          admin/users#update
                         DELETE /admin/users/:id(.:format)          admin/users#destroy
                    root        /                                   home#index
```

And here is an excerpt from the logs

```
Started POST "/admin/users/batch_action" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-01-18 23:07:07 +0530
Processing by Admin::UsersController#create as HTML
```

Why is `/admin/users/batch_action` getting routed to `Admin::UsersController#create`, when the routes shows
`batch_action_admin_users POST   /admin/users/batch_action(.:format) admin/users#batch_action`

I am using ActiveAdmin and these are the routes that it generates.

Comment: Solved: Turns out that I was overriding a member action for a custom create method instead of a collection action in the ActiveAdmin controller. This was causing `/admin/user/batch_action` to be interpreted as a POST to `/admin/users/:id` where :id was _batch_action_

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are using `resources` for routing admin/users controller, so POST http verb is defaulted to `create` action in the controller.

If you would like to add another restful POST controller action, do something like this,

```rb
scope "admin" do
  resources :users do
    member do
      post 'batch_action'
    end
  end
end
```

I don't know how your routes.rb looks like, so it might look different in your routes.rb file. But it should look similar.

Comment: Thanks, your answer finally led me to what I was doing wrong.